# Pandas : how do I merge minute data rows in a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

I have intra-day stock data in the following format.

```
             09:30:00    09:31:00    09:32:00    09:33:00    09:34:00    09:35:00
2011-01-01  -0.358525   -0.185970   -0.357479   -1.486157   -1.101909   -1.957380
2011-01-02  -0.489747   -0.341163    1.588071   -0.146610   -0.185834   -0.872918
2011-01-03   0.682824   -0.344875   -0.641186   -0.501414    0.877347    2.183530
```

I want to convert it in a time series data which looks like this.

```
2011-01-01 09:30:00   -0.358525
2011-01-01 09:31:00   -0.185970
2011-01-01 09:32:00   -0.357479
2011-01-01 09:33:00   -1.486157
2011-01-01 09:34:00   -1.101909
2011-01-01 09:35:00   -1.957380
2011-01-02 09:30:00   -0.489747
2011-01-02 09:31:00   -0.341163
2011-01-02 09:32:00    1.588071
2011-01-02 09:33:00   -0.146610
2011-01-02 09:34:00   -0.185834
2011-01-02 09:35:00   -0.872918
2011-01-03 09:30:00    0.682824
2011-01-03 09:31:00   -0.344875
2011-01-03 09:32:00   -0.641186
2011-01-03 09:33:00   -0.501414
2011-01-03 09:34:00    0.877347
2011-01-03 09:35:00    2.183530
```

I tried few panda functions, but not successful. I am new to python, any help or tips appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) method for this:

```
In [130]: s = df.stack()

In [131]: s
Out[131]: 
2011-01-01  09:30:00   -0.358525
            09:31:00   -0.185970
            09:32:00   -0.357479
            09:33:00   -1.486157
            09:34:00   -1.101909
            09:35:00   -1.957380
2011-01-02  09:30:00   -0.489747
            09:31:00   -0.341163
            09:32:00    1.588071
            09:33:00   -0.146610
            09:34:00   -0.185834
            09:35:00   -0.872918
2011-01-03  09:30:00    0.682824
            09:31:00   -0.344875
            09:32:00   -0.641186
            09:33:00   -0.501414
            09:34:00    0.877347
            09:35:00    2.183530
dtype: float64
```

This creates a Series with a multi-index (index with two levels). To merge both levels into one index, you can do (for each index entry, I just concatenate both levels with a space in between):

```
In [132]: s.index = [" ".join([l1, l2]) for l1, l2 in s.index]

In [133]: s
Out[133]: 
2011-01-01 09:30:00   -0.358525
2011-01-01 09:31:00   -0.185970
2011-01-01 09:32:00   -0.357479
2011-01-01 09:33:00   -1.486157
2011-01-01 09:34:00   -1.101909
2011-01-01 09:35:00   -1.957380
2011-01-02 09:30:00   -0.489747
2011-01-02 09:31:00   -0.341163
2011-01-02 09:32:00    1.588071
2011-01-02 09:33:00   -0.146610
2011-01-02 09:34:00   -0.185834
2011-01-02 09:35:00   -0.872918
2011-01-03 09:30:00    0.682824
2011-01-03 09:31:00   -0.344875
2011-01-03 09:32:00   -0.641186
2011-01-03 09:33:00   -0.501414
2011-01-03 09:34:00    0.877347
2011-01-03 09:35:00    2.183530
dtype: float64
```

Assuming you started from string index and column labels, you can now convert the string index to a real DatetimeIndex:

```
In [135]: s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index)
```